# Bootstrap 3 Table Replacement

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have clickable table "rows" with 2 badges aligned to the right.
Since i have only 1 td on each row, i'm pretty sure that i can replace the table with a list. Tried the List-groups components but i didn't succeed to add the badges properly (can't make it responsive like the table, which looks nice on mobile too).

Basically, i want to accomplish what i have in the attached example but without table and more clean code:
http://www.bootply.com/hdMRA7kECz

This is what i've tried so far:
http://www.bootply.com/vCnyrAP1JS

When you try this on mobile and resize the list, the badges keeps getting cut at the bottom of the list item.

Comment: Your 'question' (if you look you aren't actually asking a question) is too broad. Have you tried coding anything your self? If so what have you tried?

Comment: i edited the question and added the code for the list groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question. I was able to simplify the code and remove the `table` tags and replace them with `div`

Leaving the top portion of the code the same here is a snippet of the HTML from the previously tabled items.

EDIT *Updated Code:*

```
<div class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <div class="custom-item">
        <a class="tbl-link" href="#">Adele ft Elvis prestly ft long text
            <span class="pull-right"><span class="badge">24 Songs</span>
                <span class="badge">3500 Views</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!--2nd item here-->
    <!--3rd item here-->
    <!--4th item here etc-->
</div>
```

Updated CSS

```
.custom-item {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.custom-item:nth-child(even) {
    background: pink;
}
.tbl-link {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:100%;
}
.tbl-link:hover {
    background: lightgray;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I am not super familiar with Bootply so [I made a JS.Fiddle if you want to see it all in action](https://jsfiddle.net/osybvn18/1/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Almost perfect, only problem is that not the whole row is clickable only when mouse over the text link or the badges ,i need whole  row will be clickable

Comment: @user1610208 updated the code and JS.Fiddle with clickable rows.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up with the previuos answer and added display: "block" to the "a" tag, but your code works the same.